# How to get rid of space in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I'm using JavaFX SceneBuilder to create FXML.
My window is just BorderPane: width of 800 and height of 625.
The top portion is a MenuBar: width use_computed_size, height 25.
And the center is a AnchorPane: width 800 and height 600. Inside of it, I use a ImageView with width 800, height 600 for background-image.

It's fully fit in SceneBuilder, but when I run as Java application, there is whitespace at the right and bottom like this:

[image]

Please help to remove it, sorry I'm newbie in JavaFx

Update: I have seperated it into 2 layout then RootLayout setCenter MainLayout, but it doesn't work too.

RootLayout.fxml:

```
<BorderPane prefHeight="625.0" prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.chotoxautinh.controller.RootController">
   <top>
      <MenuBar prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="800.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <menus>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
   </top>
</BorderPane>
```

MainLayout.fxml:

```
<AnchorPane prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.chotoxautinh.controller.MainController">
   <children>
      <ImageView focusTraversable="true" layoutX="735.0" layoutY="521.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" styleClass="ruleButton" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="25.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="23.0">
         <cursor>
            <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
         </cursor>
         <image>
            <Image url="@../../../../resources/images/rule-button.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <ImageView fitHeight="600.0" fitWidth="800.0" pickOnBounds="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../../../../resources/images/background.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <VBox alignment="CENTER" layoutX="510.0" layoutY="172.0" prefHeight="330.0" prefWidth="290.0" spacing="29.0" styleClass="mainButtonLayout">
         <children>
            <Button defaultButton="true" focusTraversable="false" mnemonicParsing="false" opacity="0.7" prefHeight="47.0" prefWidth="220.0" text="CLASSIC MODE">
               <cursor>
                  <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
               </cursor>
            </Button>
            <Button defaultButton="true" focusTraversable="false" mnemonicParsing="false" opacity="0.7" prefHeight="47.0" prefWidth="220.0" text="ENDLESS MODE">
               <cursor>
                  <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
               </cursor>
            </Button>
            <Button defaultButton="true" focusTraversable="false" mnemonicParsing="false" opacity="0.7" prefHeight="47.0" prefWidth="220.0" text="MULTIPLAYER">
               <cursor>
                  <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
               </cursor>
            </Button>
            <Label style="-fx-text-fill: #333;" text="Designed by ChoToXauTinh - ©2015 Paduvi.Ltd" translateY="33.0" />
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: It is very difficult to say which component is responsible for the space without any code. Can you add the FXML to your question?

Comment: You could use [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/) to examine the scene. As ItachiUchiha mentions we only could guess without code.

Comment: sorry guys, I have added fxml code above

Comment: @ViệtXấuTính What do you have in the style class `ruleButton` ?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha  -fx-focus-traversable: true;